# Exchange migration 2003>2010 external URL

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I have an existing Exchange 2003 server (working fine). I am currently transitioning to Exchange 2010. 2k3 will remain in place while I move mailboxes to 2k10.

When setting up the new server, I have set the external URL for 2k10 to mymail.domain.com. Currently users connect to the 2k3 instance at mail.domain.com. I have noticed further along in the migration that I (think) I can set it up so they could have the same external URL and I did not need to create a different external URL for 2k10.

Was this necessary? Can I keep the same external URL for both servers (they will be both running together for some time). I would prefer to keep it one URL ("mail.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is once you are ready to move mailboxes over to your 2010 side, change your mail.domain.com to point to the 2010 system, and create a new record `legacy.domain.com` that points to your old 2003 system.  In the 2010 system you can set a Legacy Exchange URL:

```
Set-OWAVirtualDirectory \OWA* -Exchange2003URL https://legacy.domain.com/exchange
```

This will allow both 2010 and 2003 users to use the same OWA site.  You must enable forms-based authentication on the Exchange 2003 front-end server to allow this to work properly.  When setup correctly, 2010 users and 2003 users will utilize the same OWA page and 2003 users once logged in will not need to re-authenticate on the 2003 OWA page, a forms based authentication request will be delivered from 2010 to 2003.

See [Upgrade from Exchange 2003 Client Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332348%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) for more info.